# No xml Tag with SimpleXML an DOM Document

Tags: php, xml, loops, dom, simplexml

I need your help with SimpleXML and DOMDocument. I will sow you my current code and will then explain my issue:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<milu xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file://milu.xsd"/>');
$dom = dom_import_simplexml($xml);
$version = $xml->addChild('VERSION', date('m.d.Y'));

    while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {


    $bev = $xml->addChild('JUICE');
    $bev->addAttribute('ID', $row["id"]);

        // var_dump($row["name1_german"]);
        $bev->addChild('01', $row["Value1"]);
        $bev->addChild('02', $row["Value1"]);
        $bev->addChild('03', $row["Value1"]);
        $bev->addChild('04', $row["Value1"]);   
}


$dom_sxe = dom_import_simplexml($xml);  // Returns a DomElement object

$dom_output = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom_output->formatOutput = true;
$dom_sxe = $dom_output->importNode($dom_sxe, true);
$dom_sxe = $dom_output->appendChild($dom_sxe);

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="milu.xml"');
echo $dom_output->saveXML($dom_output, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

The output of the first row of the generated .xml File is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Is it with DOMDocument possible that this is not showing up?

And my second question is, that I want a  child around the loop like this:

```
<JUICE ID="0000000000">
  <CONFIG MODELID="2">
    <01>value1</01>
    <02>value2</02>
    <03>value3</03>
    <04>value4</04>
  </CONFIG>
</JUICE>
```

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the XML declaration tag use the [`documentElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.documentelement) property which outputs only the root and its children:

```
echo $dom_output->saveXML($dom_output->documentElement, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

To add the *CONFIG* child, simply add a child under `$bev` and assign each numbered node as its children:

```
if ($res = $dbconn->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {

        $bev = $xml->addChild('JUICE');
        $bev->addAttribute('ID', $row["id"]);

        $config = $bev->addChild('CONFIG');
        $config->addAttribute('MODELID', '2');

        $config->addChild('01', $row["Value1"]);
        $config->addChild('02', $row["Value2"]);
        $config->addChild('03', $row["Value3"]);
        $config->addChild('04', $row["Value4"]);  
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
<milu xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file://milu.xsd">
  <VERSION>12.04.2016</VERSION>
  <JUICE ID="0000000000">
    <CONFIG MODELID="2">
      <01>value1</01>
      <02>value2</02>
      <03>value3</03>
      <04>value4</04>
    </CONFIG>
  </JUICE>
</milu>
```

Finally, do note `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated in PHP 5 and entirely removed in PHP 7. Consider using a different PHP MySQL API such as mysqli or PDO. Above shows a fetch in mysqli.